# How to create a loop without command "for" in Bugs?

Tags: bayesian, bugs

I'll try to make an example to make it easier to understand the question.

```
model{    
constant1=(number)
constan2=(number)  
  for(j in 1:k){ #k defined in data

       a[j] ~ dgamma(c[j],d[j])
       b[j]~ dgamma(e[j], f[j])
       c[j] ~ dgamma(constan1,constant2)
       d[j] ~ dgamma(constan1,constant2)
       e[j] ~ dgamma(constan1,constant2)
       f[j] ~ dgamma(constan1,constant2)    }

    l[i]<-

 }
```

I want to make a likelihood ( l ) that is a sum of elements in 1:k (for each i => a simple loop would solve it..), but unlike R, in bugs  I cannot make a for() function or a sum function to make l[i] (multiple definitions..).

It's impossible to do something like this in bugs (it accepts only one specification).

```
 for(i in N){ #N is a number defined on data, k also    
   l[i]<-0    
 for(j in 1:k){

       l[i]<-l[i]+ d[j]*log(c[j])-log(d[j])+loggam(c[i])+pow(a[j],b[j])+a[j]*t[i] + 
delta[i]*a[j]

  #it's just an example.. t and delta is in data

   }
}
```

I tried to make this l[i] using functions sum and inprod, bugs doesn't allow to make log() of a function.
Also, i keep getting errors when i use inprod with 2 "distributions", like c and d (inprod(d,c)).
And, if I make a l[i] specification directly with a sum all 1:k it gets a error of complex/too many constants.

Any idea how to write it in a simple way and make a sum all at once of all 1:k?

I am stucked, would be very usefull any comment.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `l[i]` on both the left and right of the `<-` assignment; BUGS will not allow this. If you want to define a node that is the sum of elements in a vector, use something like the following;

```
for(i in 1:10){
   vec[i] <- some.function.of(i)
}
my.sum <- sum(vec[1:10])
```

Comment: I've got some answers in my email, it worked doing a matrix[i,j] and summing in j for each [i], something just as you suggested, thanks for the answer! By the way, i'm using bugs by R + BRugs, how can I get the simulated data for the parameters? By the commands (samplesStats("*") and samplesDensity) i get the mean, sd, error median, and a density. I tried to search even in the manual of the package, and couldn't find the answer

Comment: If you want to forward sample data, just add a new node to the model. See the "y.new" node here;

http://classes.soe.ucsc.edu/ams206/Winter03/h34m18.pdf

This idea is used a lot in posterior predictive checks; see use of "y.rep" here;

http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/presentations/ggr2handout.pdf